# Algorithmic Exam

Tags: algorithm, uml

I'm currently studying IT development in my last year, in France.
But, in my final exam, I've met this question :

[image]
The answer are :

```
1) If (A != B) { C } else { D }
2) while ( A < B ) { D; C; }
3) for (A;B;C;) { D; }
```

I have the correction of the school, but I want to compare with your point of view :)

Thanks so much,

And as we say in France "Bonne Soirée" !!

Maxime

Comment: Are you saying you've taken your exam and had the results corrected by your school?

Comment: There seems to be a condition + a loop, number 2) is the only one that has both

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title, so that other users with a similar problem can find it.

Comment: Are you sure that you copied answer 3 correctly? Seems like it has an extra semicolon after the C.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 3)

in for loop we have three part in (;;)
first part is the initialization of the loop, the second part is to determine if the for loop should be executed, and the third part is what you do after every loop.

Try this example

```
if(int a = 0;a<10;a++){
      Console.Write(a);
}
```

you may treat `int a = 0` as A, `a<10` as B, `a++` as c, `Console.Write(a)`as D.
See what you get.

Answer (score 0):

IF you wrote the answer 3) correctly(with the C's semicolon)

Since the problem lacks a lot of details, I will make an educated guess and say that the correct answer should be number 2) based on the following:
-you can see that it verifies a condition between A and B, and if that condition is met, it will access the variables(or statements,as I said, the problem lacks details) D and C
-after accessing the C variable,it goes back to verify the condition in the loop(it doesn't go straight to A which makes me think the answer is 3), but it has a syntax error)
-if the condition in the loop is unmet (false), it will exit

Else , if there is no semicolon after C, the answer would be 3) based on the fact that it checks only B and doesn't go back to A as in the loop